# JSF upgrade on JBoss 4.2.2 GA

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, jsf-1.2

I am using JBoss-4.2.2 GA. JSF libs used are with version 1.2. Is it fine to upgrade to the latest version of JSF with JBoss-4.2.2 GA?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you upgrade jsf,you can face some problems.

Here is link which explain known issues and explains some problems

[UpgradeJBossASToJSF2](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/UpgradeJBossASToJSF2)

Comment: Helpful answer but we need some additional code changes to make everything working fine.